# Priority search on columns

Tags: postgresql

**Description:**

We are using PostgreSQL 9.3 - Centos 6 x64 . We have a dtsc_search_data table as below:

```
dtsc_search_data 
id ---- c1 ---- c2 ---- c3
1  ----  1 ----  1 ----  1 
2  ----  1 ----  2 ----  2 
3  ----  1 ----  1 ----  3
```

We want to search on **"c1, c2, c3"** coloumns on **dtsc_search_data** table with conditions: if ***seach_value*** is found on "c1" then return ;  if ***search_value*** is not found on "c1" then finding on "c2", if search_value is found on "c2" then return ; else return (c3).

**Example:**

```
search_value = 1 => "c1" = 1 => just search on "c1"
search value = 2 => "c1" != 2, "c2" = 2 => just search on "c2". 
search_value = 3 => "c3"
```

**CODE** (update)

```
create table dtsc_search_data (id int, c1 int, c2 int , c3 int) ;
 insert into dtsc_search_data values(1,1,1,1);
 insert into dtsc_search_data values(2,1,2,2);
 insert into dtsc_search_data values(3,1,1,3);

 -- search_value = 2
 -- find on c1 column first
     select * 
     from dtsc_search_data
     where c1 = 2
 -- if c1 is not found then c2 -- get value from here
     select * 
     from dtsc_search_data
     where c2 = 2
```

**Question:**

Our solution: write 3 SQL queries search on "c1", "c2", "c3" are followed by conditions above. How can we do that with lowest performance ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I've totally grasped what you mean, but would the [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html) function be of use?

Comment: Thanks Veace. I just update my question to make it clearly. I can not use "coalesce" function in where clause as my condition. (where COALESCE(c1=2, c2=2, c3=2) ?? )

Comment: If you search for the value `1` I assume **only** the first row of your sample data should be returned?

Comment: Will  you know in advance for certain that only one of the values will match?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: 3 rows are returned and because we found value = 1 on  "c1" , so we do not search  on "c2" .

Comment: @Vérace: in my case:  I have a keyword to search on  "c1", "c2", "c3" sequentially. if values matched on "c1", we get all matched rows & do not search on "c2", "c3".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple OR condition will do this:

```
select * 
from dtsc_search_data
where c1 = 2
  or (c1 <> 2 and c2 = 2)
  or (c1 <> 2 and c2 <> 2 and c3 = 2);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d1ca1/1

Comment: From " or (c1 <> 2 and c2 = 1 and c3 <> 1) "  , value for comparison on c2 and c3 can not the same ? Example if  search value = 2 , result will be returned 1 rows, but if I assign 2 to " or (c1 <> 2 and c2 = 2 and c3 <> 2)" , it is returned empty. (rewrite it for my test function: select * 
from dtsc_search_data
where c1 = $search_value
  or (c1 <> $search_value and c2 = $search_value and c3 <> $search_value)
  or (c1 <> $search_value and c2 <> $search_value and c3 = $search_value); )

Comment: @Innnh Sorry, `or (c1 <> 2 and c2 = 1 and c3 <> 1) ` was a copy & paste error. Was playing around with different search values. And the `c3 <> 2` in second condition was wrong.

Comment: This is equivalent to `c1 = 2 or c2 = 2 or c3 = 2`, unless PostgreSQL does short-circuiting. (Logically, it would still be equivalent, of course.)

Comment: How about "like" condition ? (change "=" to "like" ). I change columns type in dtsc_search_data from int to text and run query: select * 
from dtsc_search_data
where ( c1 like '%2%' ) 
  or (((c1 like '%2%' ) is false) and c2 like '%2%' )
  or (((c1 like '%2%' ) is false) and ((c2 like '%2%' )  is false) and c3 like '%2%' );

Comment: Good answer, besides it is most probably wrong. Such query may return a row where `c2=needed-value` even when there is another row with `c1=needed-value`. All conditions are per-row, first condition in `c1<>2 and c3=2` does not mean "when there is no row with c1=2", it just means "any row where c1<>2".